# Si "greña" es un enredo, ¿por qué "desgreñar" significa enredar algo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, prefijos

[Desgreñar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D2C7BXo) es definido como "Descomponer, desordenar los cabellos". ¿Por qué no significa ordenar los cabellos?

Answer (score 3):

-Des es semejante al negativo (de) en inglés pero es un amigo falso porque también ["indica exceso o demasía"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn) como deslenguado y desmigajar.

Para colmo de males, desentrañar, desenredar, y desenmarañar por otro lado, utilizan [des](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn) como negación.

Comment: No entiendo lo de falso amigo en este caso porque nadie traduce del inglés el prefijo *des-*. Además los dos vienen del latín y significan casi lo mismo, no siempre es una negación en inglés tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en este caso ***"des"***, es más cercano a **destruir/descomponer** que a la negación, habría que entender que es "Greñar" para saber que es ***"desgreñar"***

Sin embargo, "greñar" no existe en el diccionario, y el significado que le das a greña es mas cercano a su entendimiento de lo complicado que es el cabello y no a su naturaleza desaliñada

Comment: Está seguro? http://dle.rae.es/?id=JWeW9dC

Comment: @user5389726598465 por favor mira la la pregunta del OP

Comment: Ahh, entiendo, está diciendo greñar no existe, y no greña.